# How to share a wireless subscription with two laptops without paying two subscriptions

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

I have one vista laptop and one XP laptop and I only have access to a wireless ISP with which I have one account.
Here’s what I have done:
On the Vista I enabled Internet sharing on the wireless adapter 
I then gave the LAN adapter a static IP and bridged the two connections
The LAN from the Vista was plugged into the WAN port of a wireless router
The XP workstation connects to the wireless router, no problem up to now

Here is the problem, the Vista pc connects to the ISP without issue and the XP connects to the router without issue. But on the XP laptop, when I open a web browser I get the ISP’s home page asking for a username and password. I can’t log in with the same ID as the vista so I can’t get anywhere.

I would like both laptops to connect without paying for two subscriptions. My ISP is TengoInternet

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up a [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) on the vista laptop, not a bridge.

I am not a windows user so I won't be able to suggest the prefered proxy server for this platform. However [privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/), [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) and [polipo](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ejch/software/polipo/) are all ported to windows.

You might want to have a look to this [Superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/57297/freeware-local-proxy-engine-for-windows) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Internet Connection Sharing builtin to the Vista machine?

So you'd have your vista machine connecting to the ISP, and both XP and Vista connect to the wifi router. If you're using a wired connection plug into the LAN ports, disable DHCP on the access point/router (so it is just a dumb device giving you a communication channel for the two machines)

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used [Jana server](http://www.janaserver.de/start.php?lang=en) to share a single network connection. This not only has proxy capability but also has a HTTP(S), FTP, and DNS server.

> The JanaServer 2 is amongst other
>   things a proxy server, that makes it
>   possible for LAN members, everyone or
>   a group as a part of the LAN, to
>   access the internet via a Modem, ISDN
>   or DSL connection. For this the
>   program must be installed on the
>   computer, that can access the internet
>   by an installed modem, ISDN or a DSL
>   adapter. No additional program on the
>   other LAN computers is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at [2hotspot](http://download.cnet.com/2hotspot/3000-2654_4-10495884.html) :

From 2hotspot  :

> A powerful software that enables the
>   instant creation of wireless hotspots
>   using your wireless router or WIFI
>   card. With this free software you can,
>   run your own free or commercial
>   wireless hotspot network; Create local
>   wireless communities where bulletin
>   board, chat, and forums available
>   locally with or without Internet
>   service; Share your broadband service,
>   split your ISP bill, control shared
>   bandwidth; Used by individuals &
>   corporations.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Wingate](http://www.wingate.com)
Setup a server on the pc logged into the wireless connection and create a client on the other laptop. Comes with a 30day trial