# Need a http proxy forwarding software with password authentication support

Tags: proxy, http-proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Freeware local proxy engine for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/57297/freeware-local-proxy-engine-for-windows)

Here I've got several http proxy servers, requiring password authentication. And clients running MS Windows have to use them separately for load balancing.

A possible solution is to install a local proxy software on every client and config them tunneling to different proxy servers. And thus all the other softwares can use a certain local proxy port instead of a remote one.

In this way, I can be free from a lot of work: when I want to remap another proxy server for a client, only the local proxy has to be configured, the rest softwares can stay untouched.

This may not be a perfect solution, but since I have no access to the proxy servers but only access to the clients, so it's still a working one.

The only problem is I can't find a fine local proxy software:

1. Privoxy is a good one but it can only be tunneled to proxy servers
   without password authentication.
2. Proxifier works but it is not free, and it doesn't listen to a
   certain port but instead intercept all the Windows connections.

So, anyone have any idea that could help?