# What is the simplest way to download with wget in remote putty terminal using my local windows internet connection

Tags: linux, proxy, putty, wget, ssh-tunnel

I'd like to initate a download using wget in a remote putty terminal (i.e. an ubuntu server), but using my local windows internet connection.

I guess there is two way to achieve this:

- run an HTTP local proxy on my windows workstation, then enable an SSH tunnel and use the created proxy
- use iptable rules to make the connected user in putty using my connection, eventually running a new kind of SSH tunnel

Is there any other way ?

Comment: Did you already try to use Putty on your Windows box to setup a http tunnel (like this: http://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/windows/ssh-port-tunneling-with-putty/ ). Requires no permanent software/setup/configuration on either end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of installing a local proxy server is probably simplest.  I've done this many times, but where the proxy server is on the ssh-server side, not client.  You just need to reverse the ssh tunnel.

I don't know if this will work without having another proxy server available, but I've used cntlm[1] on windows to simplify dealing with authenticating corporate proxies.  On linux I use squid, more from inertia than anything, though nowadays varnish seems more popular.  [2] has some other suggestions.

[1] http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/
[2] [Freeware local proxy engine for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/57297/freeware-local-proxy-engine-for-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you're trying to tunnel `http://google.com/?q=ssh+tunnel`:

In PuTTY:

1. **Settings > Connection > SSH > Tunnels**
2. Source port: `40000`
3. Destination: `google.com:80`
4. Type: `Remote`

Then on the remote ssh session:

```
wget localhost:40000/?q=ssh+tunnel
```

This won't work if the website you're trying to download issues a redirect, though.